# Size of < and > in sectops in relation to hyper references

Tags: pdf, helvetica, fontfamily

When we have a MWE like:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Test$<$ T $>$ Math mode}
\section{Test< T > Non math mode}
\section*{Test$<$ T $>$ Math mode}
\section*{Test< T > Non math mode}
Just text

Test$<$ T $>$ Math mode

Test< T > Non math mode
\end{document}
```

we get the warnings

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 9.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 9.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 9.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 9.
```

these warnings come from the usage of the math mode in the `section`.
A solution would be to use the simple `<` and `>` but due to the fact that we also have to use:

```
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

these simple characters are a bit smaller than when using the math mode version, as can be seen in:
[image]

Using pdflatex:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.5.31)
```

- is there a way to get ride of the warnings and simultaneous keep the larger `<` and `>`?

Comment: `\texorpdfstring{$<$}{<}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, looks good to me. I used the `texorpdfstring` at another place already for a complete string this is just for a single character). Maybe you could make an answer out of it.

Comment: The spacing looks flaky.  Maybe this is just the example for this posting, but if it's in the real context, do think about it.  Also, the surrounding text here is bold, but the "large" symbols aren't; that too could be improved.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I agree that the "large" symbols would indeed be better of to be bold here. How can this automatically be accomplished? Note: the texts are automatically generated and the text in the section and the "plain" text are written through the same routine. Note in principle it is possible to "wrap" the section code a bit as for the `\section` we already use a newcommand.

Comment: @barbarabeeton forgot it in the previous comment, the spacing is intentionally

Comment: Regarding making the less- and greater-than bold automatically, if there is no other math in the scope of that text, you could try including `\boldmath` within the limited environment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Interesting thought. I don't think there will be other math there , probably quite feasible.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I gave it a try and added it to the last part of the `@startsection` which now reads: `{\raggedright\normalfont\Large\bfseries\boldmath}` I do see it is a bit bolder but not very much, any other suggestions.

Comment: The degree of boldness depends on the available font.  The text font you are using is quite a bit bolder than most fonts I'm familiar with (it falls into the category sometimes designated as "black"), so unfortunately I don't have any other reasonable suggestions.

Comment: @barbarabeeton pity but thanks a lot for the effort